Как вставить изображение в Adobe Illustrator с помощью модуля win32com.client
Нужно вставить картинку питоновским скриптом в Adobe Illustrator, использую модуль win32com.client, вроде раньше можно было использовать метод Place(), сейчас в документации не могу найти ничего похожего, может кто знает?

import win32com.client

# Путь к файлу изображения, который нужно вставить
image_path = r"C:\path\to\your\image.jpg"

# Открываем Adobe Illustrator
app = win32com.client.Dispatch("Illustrator.Application")
app.Visible = True

# Открываем документ (если нужно создать новый, можно использовать Add())
doc = app.Open(r"C:\path\to\your\file.ai")

# Вставляем изображение
try:
    # Используем метод Place()
    image = doc.PlacedItems.Add()  # Добавляем новый объект для размещенного изображения
    image.File = image_path         # Указываем путь к изображению
    image.Embed()                   # Встраиваем изображение в документ, если нужно
    
    print("Изображение успешно добавлено")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Ошибка при добавлении изображения: {e}")

Если метод Place() не работает, то Add() и указание .File может быть как решение

спасибо, нормально работает
